# HereMap PositioningListener Was Never Called

Tags: android, here-api

I am pretty new on **HereMap**. I'd spent some time but I still cannot see what's wrong on this. I had the HereMap initialized with the following codes.

```
    MapFragment gmMapFragment = ...

    gmMapFragment.init(Common.main_activity, new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
            if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {

                gmMapFragment.getMapGesture().addOnGestureListener(gestureListener);

                gmMap = gmMapFragment.getMap();

                // Set the map center to the Vancouver region (no animation)
                gmMap.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(tw.latitude, tw.longitude, 0.0),
                    Map.Animation.NONE);
                // Set the zoom level to the average between min and max
                gmMap.setZoomLevel((gmMap.getMaxZoomLevel() + gmMap.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);

                gmMap.setProjectionMode(Map.Projection.MERCATOR);

                gmMap.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);

                gmPositioningManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
                gmPositioningManager.addListener(new WeakReference<>(positionListener));

                gmPositioningManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);

            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment,"
                    + error.name() + "," + error.getDetails() + "," +error.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    });
```

and I had my positionListener declared like the codes below:

```
private PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener positionListener = new
    PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener() {

    public void onPositionUpdated(PositioningManager.LocationMethod method,
                                  GeoPosition position, boolean isMapMatched) {

        // set the center only when the app is in the foreground
        // to reduce CPU consumption
        if (!paused) {
            gmGeoCoordinate = position.getCoordinate();
        }
    }
```

I am very sure that the map has been initialized successfully, `gmMapFragment.init(..)`, because I could see the map on the screen. If I use the coordinate that I got from Google map tools, I could even draw the route on the here map. But I do need the here map to get the current location for me because we need to do the 3D turn-by-turn.

But the `onPositionUpdated(...)` never got called. Did I need to do anything else make it work? I thought that adding the listener to the PositionManager is good enough.

Comment: Try with -  `gmPositioningManager.addListener(new WeakReference<PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener>(positionListener));`

Comment: You can try listening to 'OnPositionChangedListener#onPositionFixChanged(LocationMethod method, LocationStatus status)' to see if you have a fix. Also, you can check the return value of 'gmPositioningManager.start', it can return false if there is a problem. You can manually check the 'LocationStatus' using 'getLocationStatus(LocationMethod method)' as well. This page may be helpful to you: [Basic Positioning](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics/map-positioning.html)

Answer (score 0):

Summary: You can try listening to 'OnPositionChangedListener#onPositionFixChanged(LocationMethod method, LocationStatus status)' to see if you have a fix. Also, you can check the return value of 'gmPositioningManager.start', it can return false if there is a problem. You can manually check the 'LocationStatus' using 'getLocationStatus(LocationMethod method)' as well. This page may be helpful to you: [Basic Positioning](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-positioning.html)